# What is an "Action<IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>,TwitterResponse>action"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Hi I've made an attempt at using Tweetsharp for a twitter application I'm building and had success on my desktop application. But when I wanted to port it to WP7, most methods required this as an argument:

```
Action<IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>,TwitterResponse>action
```

I'm not really sure what the method is asking for. I didn't have to use this in my desktop app. Can someone explain what it's asking for or maybe point me to the proper documentation so I can understand how this works? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's describing a method that takes two arguments, `IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>` and `TwitterResponse` and has a void return type.  There are many ways to satisfy this from the concise: `(status, response) => blah` to an ordinary method:

```
private void MyMethod(IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status, TwitterResopnse response) 
{
    blah
}
```

The latter for example can be passed to those methods directly:

```
obj.SomeTwitterMethod(Mymethod);
```

Comment: So why would wp7 require this as opposed to a regular desktop application. Is it because it's waiting for a response and executes the code when it returns?

Comment: @loyalpenguin, since I'm not familiar with the API in question, I can only guess.  But you are right that this an asynchronous pattern, and WP7 is built on top of Silverlight, which doesn't allow (or at least frowns on) synchronous calls.

Answer (score 6):

This is a delegate that encapsulates a method that does not return a value, but takes two parameters: an `IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>`, and a `TwitterResponse`. MSDN's documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx).